# custom y scale in plot for

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file, looking like

```
550 1.436e+00 7.857e-01 5.906e-01 4.994e-01 4.574e-01 4.368e-01 4.260e-01 4.273e-01 4.296e-01 4.406e-01 4.507e-01 4.639e-01 4.821e-01 5.008e-01 5.156e-01 5.378e-01 5.589e-01 5.768e-01 5.970e-01 6.196e-01 6.422e-01 6.642e-01
```

The first column is for x-axis, the rest ones are for the y-axis, 22 curves totally.

I want to plot the data so that y tics represent cube roots of the values. Actually, I want my cubic curves to become linear, to show, that they're cubic in the normal coordinates (and it is fixed by my task to use these coordinates).

I tried to use the following command:

```
plot for [i=2:23] datafile using 1:(i ** .333) smooth cspline
```

It expects column number in place of i.
I know, the following is correct:

```
plot datafile using 1:($2 ** .333) smooth cspline
```

giving me the desired plot for my first line. But how do I modify this for `plot for`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the column number in place of `i`, you should use `column(i)` in the using specification.

```
plot for [i=2:23] datafile using 1:(column(i) ** .333) smooth cspline
```

Comment: Thank you, I've lost my hope googling!

Comment: @gluk47 -- No problem.  This isn't one you run into very frequently since the shorthand $X is much more common in the documentation, but I'm guessing `$i` doesn't work here (although I haven't tried it ...)

Comment: `$i` does not work, I tried it first of all. I forgot to mention it in my question.